# Windows Rename Sub Folders Command

Tags: windows, command, batch-file

Firstly not sure if this is the right place for a question like this, but here goes.

I have a folder structure of

parentfolder/folder1/10-31-2010/file1.pdf

```
        /folder2/10-31-2010/filey.pdf
        /folder3/10-31-2010/filex.pdf
        /foldern/10-31-2010/filen.pdf
```

I need to rename the date to 2010-10-31.

This is a once off thing that will only every happen on one the one parentfolder. But well over 10000 folders to apply this to.

From googling I see there are many file renaming tools, but I am not allowed to install any software on the server, nor am I allowed to move the folders off the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont see any c#/java tag; you want to do this via batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that from a `.bat` file, you can use the DOS [`ren`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true) command.

```
ren C:\folder2\10-31-2010 C:\folder2\2010-10-31
```

[This answer](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-file-for-renaming-folders/15430.html) has an script in it that might help you.

Comment: I tried the solution from Razor 2.3 in the article you referenced as is. Because of the paramters. Anyway, I created the bat file and put it in my parentfolder and ran it to replace "10-31-2010" with "2010-10-31". I received an error that the file cannot be moved because it was being used by another process. But the files, nor folders were not open anywhere.

Comment: Just tried C:\Test>ren c:\Test\A0002843 c:\Test\test and got a syntax error

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `"`(quotation). Both `ren` and `move` works fine. Just ran a test. Use `ren`: `C:\ren folder1 folder11`; Use `move`: `C:\move folder1 folder11`; Let me know error description if you come across any. Note that `folder1` contains a file within it.

Comment: C:\Test>ren: "c:\test\A0002843" "c:\test\test1"
The syntax of the command is incorrect. - I'm missing something obvious - the folder does exist.

Comment: On the command prompt type `move/?` and see if returns the help. Use the help to prepare your command. Similarly, `ren/?` will show you its help.

Comment: Yeah thanks it works. I was putting the full path as the second parameter. Will relook at the script.

Comment: Glad, I was able to help. (0:

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using shell scripts.

```
!/bin/bash
FOLDER=/path/to/*/
FILES=$(find $FOLDER -name '*-*-*')
for f in $FILES
do
    o=${f%/*}
    p=${f##*/}
    mv $f $o/$(echo $p | awk -F"-" '{ print $3"-"$1"-"$2 }')
done
```

That still uses mv and awk, hope your server have both on it.

Comment: No it does not. It is a windows 2003 server. I have no rights to install anything.